# Why doesn't it connect to the database remotely Python?

Tags: python, database, ssh, pycharm, hosting

I am writing an online application. Rented hosting on TimeWeb, created a database on the hosting. *I successfully connected to it using Putty*, but the problem is that I need to connect using pycharm. Don't be surprised that I'm making an ssh connection here, and not in the ssh terminal of pycharm, I'm just planning to create an .exe file.*I tried to specify port 3306 and utf8 encoding, but it still didn't help.* **So what's my mistake?**

```
import paramiko
import pymysql
host = "x.x.x.x"
port = 22
username ="cv86943"
password = "xxxxxx"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host,port,username,password)

print("1") #1 writes, so the connection to the hosting is successful
conn = pymysql.connect(host = "localhost",user = "cv86943_letter", password = "12345678", db = "cv86943_letter")

print("2") #But 2 does not write anymore
ssh.close()
```

**UPD: returns an error**

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([WinError 10061]...)
```

Comment: Why don't you use the inbuilt python mysql connector? And make sure destination server's port (3306) is open.

Comment: And if the port is closed 3306 then it needs to be opened?

Comment: Yes. MySQL is normally operating on 3306. Maybe the SQL server is running on a different port.

Comment: As it turned out: the database is running on port 3306. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I am using phpMyAdmin?